# How use python login k8s vm like virtctl

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to using python to login k8s visual machine(kubevirt) and execute some command like ping.
I can use virtctl to login k8s visual machine.

```
virtctl console vm-name -n namespace
```

How can I login k8s vm by python and execute command like ping ${host}?

Comment: What's a "k8s VM"; one of the Nodes, one of the individual Pods, something else?  Why do you need to send ICMP packets out of it?  Can you have one of your containers do this operation in response to a normal network request?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: K8s VM is a virtual machine which run in k8s pod supported by kubevirt. I need to write  automated testing to call kubevirt restful api to create vm and login the vm and make sure the network is correct.